# LDAP authentication Database Authorisation using SpringSecurity JSF2 and PrimeFaces

Tags: spring, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-security

I would like create an application which authenticate against an LDAP Server an the users authorities  are derived from the database.I can find a complete exemple.note that i'am not familiar with Spring security . it will be great if you guide me or any one how have source code can share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

In the spring sample projects on Github you will find several sample applications, have a look [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/tree/master/samples).